# many to many table relationship for allowing a photo to be on multiple albums in a mysql image gallery

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, photo-gallery

I am creating a mysql powered online photo album and so far I have 3 tables with schemas:

#### Photos:

- *imageID* (primary key)
- caption
- album_title
- image_url
- date_taken

#### Albums:

- album_title
- date_created
- date_modified
- *album_ID* (primary key)

#### Users:

- *userID* (primary key)
- username
- email

I know that in order to allow for users to put a photo on multiple albums, I need to create a fourth table and not put `albumID` in the `Photos` table (which doesn't allow a photo to be on multiple albums).
What should I change about my schema (if anything) and what do I put on my fourth table to allow for a single image to be on multiple albums?

PS I am using `phpmyadmin` to create my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Albums_Photos: album_id, image_id`

Try and keep your naming consistent... i.e. you have imageID and album_ID.
Personally when an ID relates to the table itself I just use ID.
So I'd have something like this:

`Photos: id (PK), caption, image_url, date_taken`
`Albums: id (PK), album_title, date_created, date_modified`
`Users: id (PK), username, email`
`Albums_Photos: album_id (FK albums.id), photo_id (FK photos.id)`

With the `Albums_Photos` table you could add an `id` column for the primary key, or you could create a composite primary key using the `album_id` and `photo_id`.

You probably want to take `album_title` out of `Photos` too.